# How to implement a merge statement for DB2 ZOS using a JdbcItemWriter in Spring Batch?

Tags: spring-batch, db2-zos

I have a requirement to read 50K records from one database and then insert or update those records into another database. The read takes a couple seconds. But the inserts/updates for those 50K records is taking up to 23 minutes even with multithreading. I have been playing with page, fetch and batch sizes but the performance isn't improving that much.

Is there a way to implement this kind of statement in a JdbcItemWriter?

```
-- hv_nrows = 3
-- hv_activity(1) = 'D'; hv_description(1) = 'Dance'; hv_date(1) = '03/01/07'
-- hv_activity(2) = 'S'; hv_description(2) = 'Singing'; hv_date(2) = '03/17/07'
-- hv_activity(3) = 'T'; hv_description(3) = 'Tai-chi'; hv_date(3) = '05/01/07'
-- hv_group = 'A';
-- note that hv_group is not an array. All 3 values contain the same values
MERGE INTO RECORDS AR
  USING (VALUES (:hv_activity, :hv_description, :hv_date, :hv_group)
     FOR :hv_nrows ROWS)
     AS AC (ACTIVITY, DESCRIPTION, DATE, GROUP)
  ON AR.ACTIVITY = AC.ACTIVITY AND AR.GROUP = AC.GROUP
  WHEN MATCHED 
  THEN UPDATE SET (DESCRIPTION, DATE, LAST_MODIFIED)
                  = (AC.DESCRIPTION, AC.DATE, CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
  WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT (GROUP, ACTIVITY, DESCRIPTION, DATE, LAST_MODIFIED)
     VALUES (AC.GROUP, AC.ACTIVITY, AC.DESCRIPTION, AC.DATE, CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
  NOT ATOMIC CONTINUE ON SQLEXCEPTION;
```

My idea is to send a bunch of rows to be merged at once and see if the perfomance improves.

I tried something like this:

```
    MERGE INTO TEST.DEST_TABLE A 
    USING (
        ('00000031955190','0107737793'),
        ('00000118659978','0107828212'),
        ('00000118978436','0095878120'),
        ('00000122944473','0106845043')
    ) AS B(CDFILIAC,CDRFC)
   ON A.CDFILIAC = B.CDFILIAC
   WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET 
        A.CDRFC=B.CDRFC,
        A.CDNUMPOL=B.CDNUMPOL
```

And while it works for DB2 LUW, it doesn't for DB2 ZOS.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to implement this kind of statement in a JdbcItemWriter?

The `JdbcBatchItemWriter` delegates to `org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcOperations`. So if `NamedParameterJdbcOperations` from Spring Framework supports this kind of queries, Spring Batch also does. Otherwise, you would need to create a custom writer.

> while it works for DB2 LUW, it doesn't for DB2 ZOS.

Spring Batch cannot help at this level, as this seems to be DB specific.